# Problem in determining constructive or destructive interference of sound waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, interference

> if two speakers are separete from each other by 5.25m and an observer
> is 50m away in the same line that on of the speakers. What type of interference exist?
>
> The speakers are in phase and have a frequency of 1.5khz.

I have problems to resolve this exercise. The formulas for destructive and destructive sound waves are not giving integer numbers.

$$\frac{diff.}{\lambda}=m$$

Constructive:
$$\frac{50.274-50}{0.2287}=1.198$$

Destructive:

$$\frac{50.274-50}{0.2287}-\frac{1}{2}=0.698$$

It's not giving me an integer number. So, what kind of interference is this?

Comment: It is in between a maximum and a minimum and nearer a . . . .  .

Comment: This also depends on the frequency of the speakers, how did you select $\lambda$?

Comment: @caverac i just added the frequency, sorry.

Comment: @Farcher to be constructive?

Comment: Where did the number $50.274-50$ come from? Which sound speed did you use?

Comment: I did a triangle with cathetus 5.25 and 50,  so 50.274 came from Pitagoras. $50.274-50$ is the path difference . The sound speed was 343m/s.

Comment: I see, if you are certain this is the correct geometry then the interference is neither totally constructive nor destructive. The observer hears a wave that has amplitude smaller than the sum of the amplitude of each speaker, but certainly larger than zero

Comment: It's not totally constructive or destructive, but is near to be constructive?  @caverac

Comment: @exsnake I would say so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to work out whether the sound wave observed is greater than that of an individual sound source (in which case the interference is constructive), or less (in which case it's destructive).

Do this by looking at the phase difference due to the path difference. When the phase difference is less than 120° ($\frac{2\pi}{3}$) the sum of the two (initially equal) amplitudes will have a magnitude greater than the individual wave; when the difference is greater, the result will be a lower amplitude.

This diagram might make that a bit clearer. In it, we have $A_1$, the amplitude of the first wave, with a reference phase of 0°. When we add it to $A_2$ with a phase difference of 90°, the resulting vector is greater than the original. But when we add it to $A_3$, with a phase angle greater than 120°, the resulting vector is shorter.

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Applying this to my question. The path difference is $0.274$ so the phase difference while be $\frac{(2\pi)0.274}{0.2287}=7.53 rad$? In this case in not completely constructive interference?

Comment: If you did the math right then I agree with your conclusion